# Почему не срабатывает click на моб. устройствах?

Tags: jquery

Вот код

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
     $('#btn0').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/index.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
  
   $('#btn1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/index.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   
   $('#btn2').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/ru.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
      
   $('#btn3').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/stream.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   
      $('#btn4').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/eu.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
      $('#btn5').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/register.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
      $('#btn6').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "include_page/gifts.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   
  });
 </script>
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
 <a href="#" id="btn1">  Home </a>
 <a href="#Teams" id="btn2">  Teams </a>
 <a href="#Stream" id="btn3">  Stream </a>
 <a href="#Brackets" id="btn4">  Brackets </a>
 <a href="#Register" id="btn5">  Register </a>
 <a href="#Prizes" id="btn6">  Prizes </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Может быть из-за  [действий браузера по умолчанию](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action) ?

Comment: оффтоп, но вот этот ваш js можно сократить до 8 строк вместо 70

Answer (score 1):

Браузеру нужно сказать, чтобы он отменил дефолтные действия по клику на ссылку. Т.е. так:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Второй, более подходящий для JQuery вариант

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
   //ajax & etc
   return false;
});
```

[Отличие preventDefault, stopPropagation и stopImmediatePropagation](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2013/05/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-preventdefault-stoppropagation-%D0%B8-stopimmediatepropagation/)

Comment: а хеши тогда как добавлять ?